# Check previous time interval for a given time depending on the minutes I want to subtract

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a procedure which will get a time and needs to output the previous interval depending on how much I need to check (5 minutes, 10, 30...) But I'm stuck with the logic.

I'm trying to know how many minutes is someone working in every interval(could be intervals of 5 or 30 minutes) for a given schedule.

So if someone works from 17:06 to 00:06. I need  to fill from 17:05 to 00:05 all the minutes worked for each interval. The macro I'm showing is only calculating when the checkin/checkout differs from 0 or the `Multiplicador` which means the interval.

```
Private Sub CalculaDesfase(Hora As Date, Inicio As Boolean, Desfase As Byte, Desfasado As Boolean, Multiplicador As Byte)

    Dim HoraFinal As Date
    If Inicio Then
        If Not Minute(Hora) Like "*" & Multiplicador And Not Minute(Hora) Like "*0" Then
            HoraFinal = Hora - TimeSerial(0, Minute(Hora), 0)
            Desfase = Multiplicador - Minute(Hora)
            Desfasado = True
            Hora = HoraFinal
        End If
    Else
        If Not Minute(Hora) Like "*" & Multiplicador And Not Minute(Hora) Like "*0" Then

            Desfase = Multiplicador - Minute(Hora)
            Desfasado = True
            Hora = HoraFinal
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

For the sake of the exercise let's just focus on the first part of the If. I can extrapolate the `Else` later.

I'm Giving:

`Hora = 09:02`
`Inicio = True`
`Desfase = 0`
`Desfasado = False`
`Multiplicador = 5`

This would work, would give me:

`Hora = 09:00`
`Desfase = 3`
`Desfasado = True`

My problem comes if I give any time higher than that. I can't wrap my mind on how to give any time and get the previous time interval. Has anyone crossed this problem before? I've searched the web but this particular case is hard to find.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not sure what you're asking, are you wanting to round a time to the nearest given unit? So you could ask 9.02 nearest previous 5 minute = 9.00 but 9.07 would give 9.05?

Comment: Exactly @jamheadart

Comment: That seems tricky yeah, trying to use excel representations of time and rounding

Comment: It would help to give a lot more examples of input/output required. What do all these other parameters mean? `Inicio = True Desfase = 0 Desfasado = False Multiplicador = True`

Comment: Sorry @Nick.McDermaid the `Multiplicador = True` should have been `5` instead. I'm trying to get the minutes worked in every interval for a given shcedule. Edited my question and added more info if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of everything going on in your VBA, but could you include a formula in your VBA like this? `=MROUND(G1,"0:05")` (obviously a VBA implementation of the idea of this formula).

[image]

EDIT:
I implemented a VBA version of this using VBA's `mod` function which does floor division, i.e -- it gets the remainder:

```
HoraFinalTemp = Minute(Hora) Mod 5 'This does floor division on 5 to get the REMAINDER
If HoraFinalTemp >= 2.5 Then 'Implement If Else logic on rounding up versus rounding down.
    HoraFinal = Minute(Hora) + 5 - HoraFinalTemp
Else
    HoraFinal = Minute(Hora) - HoraFinalTemp
```

Full Code:

```
Private Sub CalculaDesfase(Hora As Date, Inicio As Boolean, Desfase As Byte, 
Desfasado As Boolean, Multiplicador As Byte)

Dim HoraFinal As Date, HoraFinalTemp as Long
If Inicio Then
    If Not Minute(Hora) Like "*" & Multiplicador And Not Minute(Hora) Like "*0" Then
        If HoraFinalTemp >= 2.5 Then 'Implement If Else logic on rounding up versus rounding down.
            HoraFinal = Minute(Hora) + 5 - HoraFinalTemp
        Else
            HoraFinal = Minute(Hora) - HoraFinalTemp
        End If
        Desfase = Multiplicador - Minute(Hora)
        Desfasado = True
        Hora = HoraFinal
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I need the previous interval, like in H2. What is the formula for H2? If it's the same, sadly won't do :(

Comment: Why not use `=IF(MROUND(G1,"0:05")>G1,MROUND(G1,"0:05")-"0:05",MROUND(G1,"0:05"))`

Comment: And you can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.MRound` to implement in VBA with the right variables in place of range address and "0:05"

Comment: I've been trying it for a while now, and this works: `HoraFinal = TimeSerial(Hour(Hora), Int(Minute(Hora) / Multiplicador) * Multiplicador, 0)`

Comment: @Damian good job figuring it out! You could also use the `mod` function in VBA. See my revised answer above.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of thinking I came across the answer. For if it helps someone:

```
Private Sub CalculaDesfase(Hora As Date, Inicio As Boolean, Desfase As Byte, Desfasado As Boolean, Multiplicador As Byte)

    Dim HoraFinal As Date
    Dim SiguienteTramo As Date
    HoraFinal = TimeSerial(Hour(Hora), Int(Minute(Hora) / Multiplicador) * Multiplicador, 0)
    Desfase = 0
    If Inicio Then
        If Not Minute(Hora) Like "*" & Multiplicador And Not Minute(Hora) Like "*0" Then
            SiguienteTramo = TimeSerial(Hour(Hora), Application.RoundUp(Minute(Hora) / Multiplicador, 0) * Multiplicador, 0)
            Desfase = Minute(SiguienteTramo) - Minute(Hora)
            Desfasado = True
            Hora = HoraFinal
        End If
    Else
        If Not Minute(Hora) Like "*" & Multiplicador And Not Minute(Hora) Like "*0" Then
            Desfase = Minute(Hora) - Minute(HoraFinal)
            Desfasado = True
            Hora = HoraFinal
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```